# Denied permissions for Synchronized Data Extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can we denied permission for synchronized data extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, My requirement is, I don't want to allow users to access synchronized data extension either in contact builder or in Subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can assign permissions to individual users just for Sync DEs if they have access to the business unit integrated with Salesforce.

You can disable their access to all Data Extensions via Roles but I guess that is not what you really want.

If Salesforce Integration (Marketing Cloud Connector) is configured at a parent Business Unit, Child Business Unit does not have access to Sync DEs in Parent Business Unit, so one option is to only grant Child Business Unit access to some users, so they only have access to Data Extensions in Child Business Units or the Shared Data Extension Folders assigned to that Child Business Units

Comment: Hi Bo Hu,  i enabled Multi-Org connector in my environment and now i hide Sync DE from user because in Sync DE i have universal customers information so now i only have to allow user to see based on that country customer information in business unit but if i will give them sync data extension access then they can see all customer information.